# How to select all records that do not have a *specific* record in a sub table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server I am trying to select parcels that do not have a particular movement. Parcels can have zero or more movements. Movements are described in a third table.

I have some parcels

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Parcels','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Parcels
END;
CREATE TABLE #Parcels(
    Id              int
    ,LocalBarcode               nvarchar(50)
    ,ForeignBarcode             nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Parcels VALUES (1, 'Sabc1', NULL)
INSERT INTO #Parcels VALUES (2, 'Sabc2', NULL)
INSERT INTO #Parcels VALUES (3, 'Sabc3', 'def1')
INSERT INTO #Parcels VALUES (4, 'xabc', NULL)
```

Associated with parcels are movements

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Movements','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Movements
END;
CREATE TABLE #Movements(
    ParcelId                int
    ,MovementCode           nvarchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (1,'MV1')
INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (2,'MV1')
INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (2,'MV2')
INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (2,'MV3')
INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (3,'MV1')
INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (3,'MV2')
INSERT INTO #Movements VALUES (3,'MV3')
```

The movements are described in detail in a third table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MovementDescriptions','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #MovementDescriptions
END;
CREATE TABLE #MovementDescriptions(
    MovementCode                nvarchar(3)
    ,MovementDesc           nvarchar(4)
)

INSERT INTO #MovementDescriptions VALUES ('MV1','Mov1')
INSERT INTO #MovementDescriptions VALUES ('MV2','Mov2')
INSERT INTO #MovementDescriptions VALUES ('MV3','Mov3');
```

I would like all parcels

1. that have no foreign barcode
2. and local barcode starts with S
3. and parcel has no Mov2 movement (the parcel can have other movements or no movements at all)

So for the above sample data I am expecting parcel Sabc1

Here is my attempt (which does not work)

```
WITH ParcelsWithNoForeignBarcodeAndNoMove2
AS (
SELECT 
    P.Id                        AS Id
    ,P.LocalBarcode             AS LocalBarcode
    ,M.MovementCode
    ,MD.MovementDesc
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY P.Id
        ORDER BY P.LocalBarcode
    )                           AS [RowNumber]
FROM #Parcels P
LEFT JOIN #Movements M ON M.ParcelId = P.Id
LEFT JOIN #MovementDescriptions MD ON MD.MovementCode = M.MovementCode AND MD.MovementDesc = 'Mov2'
WHERE 
    UPPER(P.LocalBarcode) LIKE 'S%'
    AND P.ForeignBarcode IS NULL
    AND MD.MovementCode IS NULL
)
SELECT
    S.Id
    ,S.LocalBarcode
FROM ParcelsWithNoForeignBarcodeAndNoMove2 S
WHERE
    S.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `not exists`. Presumably also from your use of `upper` your collation is case-sensitive. From your simple description, you need:

```
select * 
from #Parcels p
where p.ForeignBarcode is null
and upper(p.LocalBarcode) like 'S%'
and not exists (
  select * from #Movements m 
  where m.ParcelId=p.Id and m.MovementCode='Mv2'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.* FROM 
#Parcels P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ParcelId, COUNT(MovementCode)MovementCode FROM #Movements WHERE MovementCode!='MV2' GROUP BY ParcelId HAVING COUNT(MovementCode)=1
    )T ON P.ID=T.ParcelId
```